# how to install sql server

Tags: sql-server

i have done a c# windows application with the back end of sql server 2008
now i want to install sql server in client machine without asking any window 
i meant the customer never wont to see the sql installation i want to install it silently i have done the setup file with installsheild 2010

tanking you
Mehaboob

Comment: Are you installing SQL Server 2008 Express ?

Comment: how is your user going to get the windows application?

Comment: @JacodeGroot no im installing 2008R2

Comment: @JeremyC. But i cant get you

Comment: I will look at updating the instructions. Why do you need 2008R2 ? It is costly from a licensing point of view and will have a negative performance impact on the user's machine. SQLExpress allows database up to 10GB in size. Personally I would not be happy with a C# application that silently install a SQL Server 2008 R2 instance without warning me.

Comment: @JacodeGroot now im changed to 2008 express tell me how can i do please

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to install SQL Server 2008 Express, you can use a [silent install](http://geekswithblogs.net/Wchrabaszcz/archive/2012/12/12/sql-2008-express-silent-installation.aspx) from a [custom action](http://helpnet.installshield.com/installshield16helplib/IHelpInsertCARulesEXE.htm):

```
Setup.exe /ConfigurationFile=SQLExpress.ini /Q
```

with your SQLExpress.ini file looking like this:

```
[SQLSERVER2008] 
INSTANCEID="SQLExpress" 
ACTION="Install" 
FEATURES=SQLENGINE 
HELP="False" 
INDICATEPROGRESS="False" 
QUIET="False" 
QUIETSIMPLE="False" 
X86="True" 
PCUSOURCE="C:\install\SqlExpress_2008\PCUSOURCE" 
ERRORREPORTING="False" 
INSTALLSHAREDDIR="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server" 
INSTANCEDIR="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server" 
SQMREPORTING="False" 
INSTANCENAME="SQLEXPRESS" 
AGTSVCSTARTUPTYPE="Manual" 
ISSVCSTARTUPTYPE="Automatic" 
ISSVCACCOUNT="NT AUTHORITY\NetworkService" 
ASSVCSTARTUPTYPE="Automatic" 
ASCOLLATION="Latin1_General_CI_AS" 
ASDATADIR="Data" 
ASLOGDIR="Log" 
ASBACKUPDIR="Backup" 
ASTEMPDIR="Temp" 
ASCONFIGDIR="Config" 
ASPROVIDERMSOLAP="1" 
SQLSVCSTARTUPTYPE="Automatic" 
FILESTREAMLEVEL="0" 
ENABLERANU="True" 
SQLCOLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" 
SQLSVCACCOUNT="NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE" 
SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS="DOMAIN\Administrator" 
ADDCURRENTUSERASSQLADMIN="False" 
TCPENABLED="0" 
NPENABLED="0" 
BROWSERSVCSTARTUPTYPE="Disabled" 
RSSVCSTARTUPTYPE="Automatic" 
RSINSTALLMODE="FilesOnlyMode"
```